# How return http_code 401 with PHP

Tags: php, curl, http-headers

I'm using cUrl in the client side.

On my webservice (ws.php), i've this simple code :

```
<?php
header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized', true, 401);
echo 'This is an error';
exit;
?>
```

When i call this ws.php page, i still have http_code = 200.

Here is my cUrl code is client side :

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "webservice_url");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_variables); //array()

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$code = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

curl_close($ch);
```

$code = 200 even i put the header code "401".

Comment: I think you can't specify http status codes with php `header()`. It may be a server thing, not quite sure, just throwing it out there in case it rings any bells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this on your ws.php:

```
<?php
ob_start();
header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
echo 'This is an error';
exit;
?>
```

Let me know if this works or not ?

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `http_response_code`:

```php
<?php
    http_response_code(401);
    echo 'This is an error';
    exit;
?>
```

This would also allow you to also add header content types, such as JSON:

```php
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    http_response_code(401);
    echo json_encode(['error'=>'This is an error']);
    exit;
?>
```

ref: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php